# Improve code with generator expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to search *a* in *d*, the below chunk of code return correct result, i.e. 3.
However, how can I write the code below into generator expression?

```
a = [4, 6]
d= {0: [0, 4], 1: [3, 6], 2: [4, 0], 3: [4, 6], 4: [6, 3], 5: [6, 4]}

for i in range(0, len(d)):
    if d.get(i) == a:
        print i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the items:

```
>>> a = [4, 6]
>>> for k, v in d.iteritems():
...     if v == a:
...             print k
... 
3
```

`d.iteritems()` returns a generator of each item in the dictionary with their key and value:

```
>>> list(d.iteritems())
[(0, [0, 4]), (1, [3, 6]), (2, [4, 0]), (3, [4, 6]), (4, [6, 3]), (5, [6, 4])]
```

If you're working with python 3, `items()` is identical to iteritems.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need range.

```
>>> a = [4, 6]
>>> d = {0: [0, 4], 1: [3, 6], 2: [4, 0], 3: [4, 6], 4: [6, 3], 5: [6, 4]}
>>> [i for i in d if d[i] == a]
[3]
>>> (i for i in d if d[i] == a)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f14d9629690>
>>> next(_)
3
```

Comment: d.get() has the benefit of returning `None` should you supply an incorrect, non-valid, or otherwise non-existent key.  Alternatively, you run the risk of throwing a `KeyError` if you try to `d[key]`; this is good practice IMO.

Comment: `d.get()` comes from OP's code. I updated the code. Thanks for comments.

Comment: ha well now I'm confused... what's wrong with having d.get() =P, I see that it still works, and it's conditional, but is there any harm?

Comment: @JustinCarroll, Iterating keys of the dictionary, `d[key]` will not raise KeyError.

Answer (score 1):

With `next()`:

```
next(k for k, v in d.iteritems() if v == a)
```

`next()` will return the first yielded result.